# Maintain aspect ratio of div containing image in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have some images divided up into two rows with widths that grow and shrink with the container as the browser window is resized.

However, the images can be any aspect ratio, and I have to constrain them to an 80 width : 53 height ratio. I've been trying all sorts of things for almost a day now to no avail. How am I supposed to achieve this?

```css
body {
  background-color: #666;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 90%;
}

.img-box {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="img-box">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553155905-b94ab6f10bc8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjU1Nzk4fQ"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="img-box">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553174975-8b6c0a0d8fc9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjU1Nzk4fQ"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="img-box">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553155905-b94ab6f10bc8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjU1Nzk4fQ"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="img-box">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553155905-b94ab6f10bc8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjU1Nzk4fQ"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="img-box">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553174975-8b6c0a0d8fc9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjU1Nzk4fQ"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="img-box">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553155905-b94ab6f10bc8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjU1Nzk4fQ"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="img-box">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553155905-b94ab6f10bc8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjU1Nzk4fQ"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="img-box">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553155905-b94ab6f10bc8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjU1Nzk4fQ"
        />
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/8x3qjompz9

**The ideal result:**

[image]

Comment: @LGSon I've added the code, can you remove your downvote please?

Comment: Next time, don't ask me (or any other) whether they downvoted or not, and to remove it if they did, simply notify about the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I have finally managed to understand what was being explained [in this article](https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/).
The container now resizes with the flex-items inside resizing along with it while maintaining the aspect ratio.

The trick in the end was to set a `padding-top: 30%` on the divs that contain the images that act as a 'height' and then giving them `position: relative`. This enabled me to give the child (now pushed down by the padding-top) `position: absolute` and put it in place at the `top:0; left:0` position.

The reason I had to use `padding-top` instead of `height` is because height is calculated from the parent, when what we want is a height that is calculated from the element's width. And `padding-top` using percentages is calculated based on the element's width.

```css
body {
  background-color: #666;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 90%;
}

.img-box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid cyan;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  padding-top: 30%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="img-box">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553155905-b94ab6f10bc8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjU1Nzk4fQ"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="img-box">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553174975-8b6c0a0d8fc9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjU1Nzk4fQ"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="img-box">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553155905-b94ab6f10bc8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjU1Nzk4fQ"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="img-box">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553155905-b94ab6f10bc8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjU1Nzk4fQ"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="img-box">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553174975-8b6c0a0d8fc9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjU1Nzk4fQ"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="img-box">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553155905-b94ab6f10bc8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjU1Nzk4fQ"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="img-box">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553155905-b94ab6f10bc8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjU1Nzk4fQ"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="img-box">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553155905-b94ab6f10bc8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjU1Nzk4fQ"
        />
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```